# using module afte requiring with WebPack

Tags: webpack

I'm starting to learn ReactJS and I have decided to use WebPack to manage dependencies. Now I wish to add, for instance [arrayJS](http://matthewmueller.github.io/array/). How can I use the provided methods after requiring it?

```
var React = require('react');
var array = require('array');

var DATA = {
  items: [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'a3' },
    { id: 3, name: 'a4' },
    { id: 4, name: 'a2' }
  ]
};

...
```

How can I sort items by name using the ['sort' method](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/array#sortstrfn-direction) provided by arrayJS?

Something like `DATA.items.sort('name')`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

arrayjs requires you to wrap your array in their constructor so after your code you can just write:

```
var wrappedArray = array(DATA.items);

var sortedArray = wrappedArray.sort('name');
```